# tabindex order not efficent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Example:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="one"></a><br>
<a href="#" id="two"></a><br>
<a href="#" id="three"></a><br>
<a href="#" id="four"></a><br>
<a href="#" id="five"></a><br>
.
.
.
<a href="#" id="amillion"></a><br>
```

If I would like the `#four` link to be displayed(with proper `css`) before the `#three` link, I would normally also want it to be selected by tab previously the `#three` link. In order to make this, I need to set the whole links(and every other tags if any) for `tabindex`, so the `#four` and `#three` will be selected in logical order by tab. This is ok, but what if I have to make `tabindex` for some `#909` link?

What is the solution to this? I can't find it anywhere... Or perhaps there's another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap a {
  order: 4
}

.wrap a:nth-child(-n+4) {
  order: 1
}
.wrap a:nth-child(3) {
  order: 2
}
.wrap a:nth-child(4) {
  order: 3
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<a href="#" id="one">1</a>
<a href="#" id="two">2</a>
<a href="#" id="four">4</a>
<a href="#" id="three">3</a>
<a href="#" id="five">5</a>
<a href="#" id="ten">10</a>
<a href="#" id="hundred">100</a>
<a href="#" id="thousand">1000</a>
<a href="#" id="tenthousand">10000</a>
<a href="#" id="hundredthousand">100000</a>
<a href="#" id="onemillion">1000000</a>
</div>
```

2:nd sample, shifted 10/100

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap a {
  order: 4
}

.wrap a:nth-child(-n+7) {
  order: 1
}
.wrap a:nth-child(6) {
  order: 2
}
.wrap a:nth-child(7) {
  order: 3
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<a href="#" id="one">1</a>
<a href="#" id="two">2</a>
<a href="#" id="three">3</a>
<a href="#" id="four">4</a>
<a href="#" id="five">5</a>
<a href="#" id="hundred">100</a>
<a href="#" id="ten">10</a>
<a href="#" id="thousand">1000</a>
<a href="#" id="tenthousand">10000</a>
<a href="#" id="hundredthousand">100000</a>
<a href="#" id="onemillion">1000000</a>
</div>
```

Comment: And what if it's the `<a href="#" id="#ninehundred">900</a>`? You would need to set the all of the previous links as well...

Comment: @franenos Updated my answer to show how you can pick any. To keep tab order and display order as you asked, the one you want to shift, need to be shifted in html + indexed in css, as done now with 3/4 ... and with 10/100